# XGBoost plot_importance cannot show full feature names

Tags: matplotlib, xgboost

I am running a XGboost regressor on a dataset, and finally plotting the feature importance.
because my feature names are long(20-60 characters), it "trims" their names in the saved image (on the left side of the image).

**code:**

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plot_importance(search.best_estimator_)
plt.savefig(f'{os.path.join(self.model_save_directory, "feature_importance.png")}')
```

I tried to set a wide image with:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (28, 7)
```

Now there are more characters in the image of each feature, but not all. On the other hand, the height of the image has shrunk a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show the full feature names with:

```
plot_importance(search.best_estimator_, max_num_features=None)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.savefig(f'{os.path.join(self.model_save_directory, "feature_importance.png")}', bbox_inches='tight')
```